# app gets crashed suddenly, error says: attempt to recursively call -save: on the context in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, crash

In my app, on button click,for every 1 second(timer1 call), I am inserting some data into the core data and for every 2 minutes(timer2 call) I am fetching inserted data to send it to the server(web service call).

Data insertion and retrieval is happening correctly but some times app is getting crashed and error says attempt to recursively call -save: on the context in core data.

is it fine to use single managedObjectContext for both fetching and insertion?

what concurrency type to be used for mangedObjectContext?(privateQueueConcurrency or mainQueueConcurrency)

[I am using Xcode 8.1 with IOS 10.1]

Comment: Do you find any solution for crash ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you don't give us much to go on, a bit more code around how you store data might help. Are you using NSPersistentContainer?  Do you wrap your operations in a context.perform() call?

To help locate where things go off the road, you might want to provide these two launching flags in your scheme:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1
```